# Buffer Overflow

Tags: c, buffer, buffer-overflow

I am trying to create a buffer overflow.  There are three variables in a function -- an int, and two arrays.  The two arrays are both a length of 14 chars.  The int is initialized to 0 in the function, but I am trying to change it to 1.  I run the program from terminal and put in some input to assign to the second array.

Therefore, when I run the program, I am doing something like this:

```
./a.out 11111111111111111111111111111
```

this is 29 1's.  So this overflows the two arrays making them both just 1's, and I want to put that 29th "1" into the int, but for some reason it gets converted into the decimal number which is "49."  How would I be able to put a "1" into this int using a buffer overflow without it converting?

I am not able to put the decimal version of 1 because it is an unprintable character in ascii.

Comment: Post the code you have written

Comment: I think you need to learn about [ASCII encoding](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ascii).

Comment: Whay are there so many posts about creating buffer overflows and hardly any about avoiding them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ASCII value of character `1` is `0x31`, which is `49` in decimal. You were on the right track.

What you are doing invokes undefined behavior anyway, but expected behavior is a form of undefined behavior.

To try and change the integer to `1`, you can run

```
./a.out 1111111111111111111111111111^A
```

Where the `^A` is the obtained by pressing <kbd>control</kbd> and the <kbd>A</kbd> keys, but the shell's line editor will usually interpret that as a command to move the cursor to the beginning of the line... so you can try this instead:

```
./a.out $(printf '1111111111111111111111111111\001')
```

Comment: this is exactly what I was looking for.  I tried doing something very similar to that, but I didn't put the printf, so it was just being encoded back into decimal like before.  Thanks!

Comment: @winsticknova: More precisely, the `printf` external command interprets the `\001` and turns it to ASCII character `0x01`, where the shell alone does not and your program would receive the string `"1111111111111111111111111111\\001"` with the actual `\\` in it.